# Is passing "props" outside of the props object an anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, functional-programming

I am using `AntD <Table />` component. When I am generating the columns I want to pass custom props to my cells that are not part of the data I am feeding the table. It could be things like theme, color palette, layout setting etc..

Each column is represented by an object and has a `render` method. AntD iterates over the rows and the columns and passes the `record` of that row to be rendered by the given `cell`.

```
{
   ... // keys like `key`, `title`, `dataIndex` ...
   render: (record) => {...}
}
```

Instead of passing my extra props to the component itself directly like this:

```
{
   ... // keys like `key`, `title`, `dataIndex` ...
   render: (record) => <MyCell {...record} extraProp={extraProp} extraProp2={extraProp2} />
}
```

I got in the habit of writing something like this:

```
{
   ... // keys like `key`, `title`, `dataIndex` ...
   render: MyCell(extraProp, extraProp2)
}
```

Where MyCell is defined as:

```
const MyCell = (extrProp, extraProp2) => props => {...}
```

Should I stick to using regular props? Or is it fine if I pass my extra props like this?

Will it incur bad performance? Will it bite me in the future, giving me bugs hard to trace?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches have a minor difference.

```
// It isn't a functional component, 
// it's curried function which returns a functional component
const generateMyCell = (extrProp, extraProp2) => props => {...}

//   ^ naming it MyCell is misleading.
```

The main difference is that the extra props (`extraProp-x`), are dynamic when using the function, and static when using the functional component:

```
//                     v The extra props are static, they won't change
render: record => (
  <MyCell {...record} extraProp={extraProp} extraProp2={extraProp2} />
);

//         v The developer shows intetation that props may change
render: generateMyCell(extraProp, extraProp2)
```

The most common way is rendering the functional component, and let the parent handle the props change.

```
// Most readable and common
const generateTableColumns = () => {
  // Handle the props here.
  const columns = [
    {
      render: (
        <MyCell {...record} extraProp={extraProp} extraProp2={extraProp2} />
      )
    }
  ];

  return columns;
};

// Usage
<Table columns={generateTableColumns()} />;
```

In conclusion, it is not an "Anti Pattern", it's a matter of what is your intents, there are occasions to use a "function that returns a component" but I doubt that it is the case.

> Note that you can add **default props** to `generateMyCell`:

```
const generateMyCell = (extrProp = def1, extraProp2 = def2) =>
props => {...}

// Call it with props when they need to change.
generateMyCell()
```